# Merging the values into one column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which merges the data from column A and B into column C.

Example :
If A1= 1 and B1 =5 , A2 = 10, A3= 7 and B3=8.

So,our C column will have C1=1,C2=2,C3=3,C4=4,C5=5, then it will skip 6 , then C6=7,C7=8,then it will skip 9 and then C8=10.

My current output:

[image]

We can see here that column A and B is the input, and we want output in column C

My problem?
In my C column, I am getting correct data but B099 is written as B99,A012 is A12 and so on. How can we avoid this? I want full numbers like B099 and A012 in C column.

My code :

```
 Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rowNo, lastRow, Val1, Val2, Val3, first, last, i, j As Variant
rowNo = 1
lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & 
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastRow
    first = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value
    last = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value
    Val1 = Mid(first, 2, 4)
    Val2 = Mid(last, 2, 4)
    Val3 = Left(first, 1)
    If IsEmpty(Range("B" & i)) = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & rowNo).Value = first
        rowNo = rowNo + 1
    Else
        For j = Val1 To Val2
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & rowNo).Value = Val3 & j
            rowNo = rowNo + 1

            Next j
        End If
        Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: try: `format(j,"000")` - i didn't study your code to hard, so you may need to wrap format around another variable or another spot, but the `format` function is an answer

Comment: @ScottHoltzman : you are the champ :) thankyou so much